# Problems driving a universal motor with triac

Tags: motor, driver, triac

I have a router, Dewalt DWP611. The controller unit burnt out, so I wanted to make something simple to control it. I made this circuit:
[image]

My motor is 110V version and I am using 200k potentiometer instead of 500k.

The motor spins, but brushes spark heavily and it uses much more current than it should (around 4-5 Amps instead of less than one). When I lower pot setting, it starts rotating with bursts, also with heavy sparks.

What am I doing wrong? I identified the motor as universal motor with series winding connection, which should run on AC or DC. I know that factory controller uses soft start, which I don't.

I have 2 units, both run the same way. See the videos, low and high rpm:

[Low RPM](https://youtu.be/Y2WXXHiX2IM)

[High RPM](https://youtu.be/lzKq3QE5PBg)

Both units were burnt the same way, after long CNC job (14 hours) and a lot  of aluminum debree. I think debree was filled and stuck inside. I opened and cleaned everything, internals look good now.

[image]

Comment: I think that you should test your motor barefoot .I hope that your motor does not have a shorted turn which would make it draw lots of current .Maybe this excess current draw burnt out the factory controller .

Comment: You may be right. Will test it.

Comment: I have 2 units, both show around 1 Ohm on the stator and the same on the rotor.

Comment: When you have a shorted turn your DCR tests appear OK .If you run your 2 units under no load on a   DC   lab supply and compare your currents .

Comment: Added videos and info.

Comment: Motor damaged and needs replacing or rewinding. Questions about repairs. Vote down.

Comment: @AltAir I see a question about designing and troubleshooting a circuit driving a motor. The fact that the OP is trying to design that circuit to replace something isn't relevant.